# How to get input's value with jQuery and submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, submit-button

I need to execute jQuery code when the submit button is pressed.

The jQuery get the value of a input field so the submit button can send it with the rest of the form.

This is my **HTML** code (submit button and input field):

```
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" name="myInput">

<button type="submit" id="mySubmit">Send</button>
```

This is my **jQuery** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mySubmit").click(function() {
        $("#myInputField").val("Hello");
    }) 
})
```

Comment: you want to **set** on the client then **get** it on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    $("#myInput").val("Hello");
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" name="myInput">

<button type="submit" id="mySubmit">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```